# Update MySQL database Table from another Table in different location

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have the following issue related to I have in localhost(my computer) a Table in a database which I use to update the data for a month. Once data is correct, I need to update the Table in the database which resides in the server.

I use Navicat to do the work and it only transfer data deleting the actual database in the server and sending all the data from my localhost.

The problem is that the Table now has almost 300.000 records stored and it takes too long transfering the data leaving the database empty for some time.

Is there any way I could use that only update the data without deleting the whole table?

Comment: I don't know Navicat, but I think that you can export from your local db and import to a working table on the server db. Then, when all your data is on the server db, you can create the update query. Working on the same db the update query is gonna be fast.

Comment: You mean creating an auxiliar Table?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export local table with different name as mysqldump or just csv, 300k rows is not a big deal and use a different table now.

then upload the table 2 to db and use a query to update table 1 using table2 data.